# Can I use sprintf () with multiple #define token strings

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor

I have two strings that may be changing independently.  I thought to make them `#defines` so I don't have to change it all over my code.  I'm having problems putting them together with `sprintf()`.

So, below, if VoltageSet was 2.2, I want to put the string "sour:volt:2.2\r" into the cmd buffer.

(FYI- SOUR:VOLT:2.2 is a SCPI command to an instrument, and \r is a carriage return to terminate the message)

In my header:

```
#define SETVOLTAGELEVEL "SOUR:VOLT:"
#define TERMINATIONCHAR "\r"
```

In my c code:

```
int SetVoltageLevel (double VoltageSet)
{
    char cmd[255]={0};
    sprintf(cmd, "SETVOLTAGELEVEL%fTERMINATIONCHAR", VoltageSet);
}
```

Am I over thinking this?  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf(cmd, SETVOLTAGELEVEL "%f" TERMINATIONCHAR, VoltageSet);
```

or

```
sprintf(cmd,  "%s%f%s", SETVOLTAGELEVEL, VoltageSet, TERMINATIONCHAR);
```

Comment: +1, I have seen many good answers from you. But you don't seem to explain much (code-only answers) which is why people are reluctant to vote you up. Perhaps, you can explain a bit in the future :)

Comment: I think to be a source of confusion if touched by an extra comment back because I think I felt very strange my English (by Google transrator). Is sufficient source code in most cases.

Comment: That seems to do it.  I think the parenthesis were wrong.  both of those implementations work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you want to achieve this with this behavior [(An XY problem?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but you can concatenate string **literals** by writing them one after another:

```
sprintf(cmd, SETVOLTAGELEVEL "%f" TERMINATIONCHAR, VoltageSet);
```

**But...**

1. ***Why?***
2. Very risky. You not only fail to use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`, but you may also run into format string errors in case the two macros define more or less format specifiers than you actually supply arguments to the function.

Comment: Perhaps and XY problem...The why is that we'll have 15 instruments that could each have different command strings. I could do a find an replace throughout my c code, but I figured it would be easier to just change them in one place, the top of the header file and leave the code alone.

I wasn't aware of snprintf(), I'll look into that, thanks. I'm pretty much a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here. Preprocessor i.e. define will be replaced by its value before compilation. So you wont see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

@BLUEPIXY has pointed out one way. Here is something closer to what you had in mind. Note that what you have does not work because the preprocessor does not expand tokens inside a string. But you can use string concatenation. Good to know.

```
int SetVoltageLevel (double VoltageSet)
{
    char cmd[255]={0};
    sprintf(cmd, SETVOLTAGELEVEL "%f" TERMINATIONCHAR, VoltageSet);
}
```